# Understand failing JUnit4 test?

Tags: java, regex, exception, junit4

The following is supposed to throw an InvalidExpression exeption if the string "what" doesn't contain an operation (+, -, *, /).

```
//Check if the input contains at least one operation
else if(!what.matches(".*[+ \\- * \\/].*")) {
    throw new InvalidExpression("No operation in the expression");
}
```

However if I run the following JUnit4 Test I don't get correct exception. The evaluate method calculates the math expression, and in theory should contain an operation.

```
@Test (expected = InvalidExpression.class)
public void test() throws InvalidExpression {
    testCalc.evaluate("5 5");
}
```

Comment: You have spaces inside the brackets. So a space is a valid operator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check the previous comment and put the full code of your solution here, so we can help you if that doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces inside the brackets. So a space is a valid operator.

Your regex should be

```
".*[+\\-*/].*"
```

Comment: This is correct and worked. Thank you. I have added your solution to the original question in the EDIT.

Comment: You shouldn't have done that. The question should contain the question, not the accepted answer. To accept the answer, check the checkmark at the left of the answer.